# Default Date Format in CSV file

Tags: oracle, date, csv

I'm creating a CSV file from my application, using oracle. When I open the csv file created, the columns which include dates are formatted in a special format such as `dd-mmm-yy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy` which is what I was expecting.

What can be the reason for that and what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Comment: just a hunch: could it have to do with the locale setting of the machine?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the default date format in NLS_DATE_FORMAT. It can be set in a lot of places: sql session (in a logon trigger), os variable, registry, pfile. Or it can be derived from settings like NLS_TERRITORY wich can be explicitly set or derived from the locale setting on the client.

```
SQL>alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY';
SQL>[select csv statements;]
```

Probably will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

use TO_CHAR(date, 'format') function on your column where the format is dd/mm/yyyyy